# Limit ESRI World Geocoding Service to a particular city using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, geocoding, geocoding-service

I'm trying to limit ArcGIS World Geocoding Service to just the city I work in. I'm using it, in conjunction with another custom geocoder to refine the results of a composite geocoder (which is published to our ArcGIS Server). However, I don't want it returning results from neighbouring cities/towns. Does any know how to go about this?

These are the settings:[image]

Comment: You could write a python script that uses the x & y from the geocode to hit a mapservice of the city layer, and if it's not in the city layer then ignore the geocode. But other than that, I don't believe that you can filter the return results of a geocoder, without custom code.